# How to get full pathname from struct dentry in Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

I'm writing my own kernel module which captures `vfs_mkdir(struct inode *, struct dentry *, int)` kernel function invocation and tries to log the on-disk pathname where this invocation occurs.

I want to use the `dentry_path` kernel function to convert `struct dentry *` to a pathname.
It's wired that when I insert the module, I get an error

> Unknown symbol dentry_path

My kernel version is 2.6.32 and it is supposed to be exported.
I can't figure out the reason.
Is there any alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [dentry_path_raw](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.9.6/include/linux/dcache.h#L339).  `dentry_path` isn't exported.

From linux-fsdevel [archives](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-fsdevel/msg54547.html):

```
On Fri, Apr 20, 2012 at 02:08:37PM -0400, Theodore Ts'o wrote:

> I wonder if we would be better off simply exporting dentry_path(),
> perhaps as EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL, with a warning that it should only be used
> for debugging purposes, or some such.  I suspect it's not worth changing
> all of the inode_ops interfaces to pass in a struct path intead of a
> struct dentry if it's only to be used for debugging.  Or maybe I should
> just keep on doing these ugly things and justify them because it's only
> for debugging (yelch).
> 
> What do you think?

Just use dentry_path_raw() - it _is_ exported and the only difference is
the lack of //deleted for unlinked ones.
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. But I didn't find the symbol `dentry_path_raw` in kernel version 2.6.32. Anything wrong with my configuration?

Comment: If you have control over the Linux build you could try updating the code to export it as you want.